# how can i turn network interface (localhost) on?

Tags: networking, interface, localhost

localhost is off on my machine.

it's described in my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

but when i run route

```
 route -n" with wireless off
```

I get:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

*how can i turn it on?*

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @tachyons Its perfectly on-topic here on Ask Ubuntu. Its a general networking question. Hence on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ifconfig` to check whether a network interface (e.g., the localhost interface (lo)) is enabled or not.

You can use `sudo ifconfig lo up` to enable the localhost interface.

Comment: sorry, "sudo ifconfig lo up" didn't change anything. maybe my case is different.